# How can an application read logs of another application ANDROID

Tags: android, logging

I want my application to read logs of another application how can I do it.

Comment: And why you want to do that ?

Comment: I want to send broadcast after a particular activity runs.

Comment: I want to broadcast message after a particular activity is running.

Answer (score -2):

if all other application is log enable then an then you are able to fetch the log of other applications

```
android:debuggable
Whether or not the application can be debugged, even when running on a device 
in user mode — "true" if it can be, and "false" if not.
```

if this key is enable in manifest than you are able to see the logs of application